# how to create columns from another dataframe rows and populate them based on values from both dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

say I have two dfs:
df1:

| new_col | attribute | y1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| petrol | car | 0.3 |
| diesel | car | 0.4 |
| rigid | hgv | 0.25 |
| artic | hgv | 0.35 |

the other data frame (df2) has the attribute column from df1 in common:

| id | car | hgv |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1000 | 10 |
| 3 | 100 | 10000 |

I am trying to add the names of new_col from df1 as new columns in df2 and populate it by multiplying y1/y2 by the corresponding attribute column in df2 for y1 and y2.

That is what I am trying to get:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex Series` by `new_col,attribute` and multiple all columns in `df2` without `id`, remove second level of MultiIndex by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html), join `df2` and last use [`DataFrame.convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) for integers columns:

```
s = df1.set_index(['new_col','attribute'])['y1']
df = df2.join(df2.drop('id',1).mul(s, level=1).droplevel(1, axis=1)).convert_dtypes()
print (df)
   id   car    hgv  petrol  diesel   rigid   artic
0   1    10   1000       3       4   250.0   350.0
1   2  1000     10     300     400     2.5     3.5
2   3   100  10000      30      40  2500.0  3500.0
```

Comment: jezrael thank you very much! it is working but it duplicates the length of the final dataframe.

Comment: I think this is happening as my id col in df2 has duplicate ids